# Failed to load resource the server responded with a status 400 - AngularJS and WebAPI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with add user to database. Adding a user runs successfully, but it shows the error like in title: **Failed to load resource the server responded with a status 400 (Bad request)**. 
I'm using AngularJS and WebApi. 
My ApiService with POST method:

```js
var ApiService = function ($http) {
    var result;
  
  this.PostApiCall = function (controllerName, methodName, obj, callback) {
        var result = $http.post('api/' + controllerName + '/' + methodName, obj).success(
            function (data, status) {
                var event = {
                    result: data,
                    hasErrors: false
                };
                callback(event);
            }).error(function () {
                var event = {
                    result: "",
                    hasErrors: true,
                    error: status
                };
                callback(event);
            })
        return result;
    };
}
```

and CreateUser method in controller:

```js
$scope.CreateUser = function () {
        var request = {
            Login: $scope.login,
            Password: $scope.password,
            Name: $scope.name,
            Surname: $scope.surname,
            Email: $scope.email,
            PhoneNumber: $scope.phoneNumber,
            DateOfBirth: $scope.dateofBirth,
            AccountTypeId: 1
        }

        Api.PostApiCall("Users", "PostUser", request, function (event) {
            if (event.hasErrors == true) {
                alert("Error!" + event.error);
            }
            else {
                alert("Hello" + $scope.name);
            }
        });
    }
```

API controller method:

public IHttpActionResult PostUser(User user)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

```
        db.Users.Add(user);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = user.Id }, user);
    }
```

Comment: By "runs successfully" do you mean that the user information ends up in the DB?

Comment: What does the API's controller method look like?

Comment: yes, user information finally are in db. API's controller method seems to be ok. While debugging everything runs okey